# How do I change/reset the mapping of the keyboard in Visual Studio 10

Tags: visual-studio-2010

My cat ran over my keyboard and since then, the mapping of my keyboard is incorrect. I think she pressed some strange shortcut.

- : maps to >
- < maps to \
- ; maps to <
- ´ maps to =

etc...

Where can I reset/correct the mapping / layout of my keyboard in Visual Studio 10?

Comment: Sounds like you normally have a non english keymap, and Windows switched over to a US keymap. Check for an `EN` button in the task tray that should allow you to switch back.

Comment: I disabled this button, but i looked in my "Systemsteuerung" (don't know what it is called in english) and deleted a strange "Virtual Ink" - Keyboard. This solved the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by deleting a strange "Virtual Ink" - Keyboard in the systemcontrol-panel.